# How to get the id of the drawable from sprite onDraw?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, sprite

I have these 2 lists :

```
private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>();
```

And here is for drawing Canvas :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
    }
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now I need to know what drawable is being used when I touch a sprite.

Here is where I (think) I'll put that code :

```
if (sprite.isCollition(event.getX(), event.getY()))
```

The id of the drawable in the R.java (the one in the hexadecimal) may do.

Comment: what do you need it for?

Comment: It's for a game with collecting objectives (like Candy Crush). Say, I need to tap 3 blue stars, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Sprite isn't a standard Android class is it? Just add the id as a member variable.